# Integration of the incomplete beta function

Tags: integration, special-functions

I would like to know if there is a way of computing the following integral analytically ($B_u$ is the incomplete beta function): $$\int B_u(a-1,0)~u^{-a} du$$

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Hi David, I already tried, but I don't find anything that way.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

The incomplete beta function in the integrand has the integral representation

$$\operatorname{B}_{x}{\left(a-1,0\right)}:=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^{a-2}}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{\Re{\left(a\right)}>1}.$$

Thus, for $\Re{\left(a\right)}>1$, integrating by parts yields:

$$\begin{align}
\int x^{-a}\operatorname{B}_{x}{\left(a-1,0\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a}\cdot\operatorname{B}_{x}{\left(a-1,0\right)}-\int \frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a}\cdot\frac{x^{a-2}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a}\cdot\operatorname{B}_{x}{\left(a-1,0\right)}-\frac{1}{1-a}\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\left(1-x\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

and you can probably take it from there.